# How to redirect users to different page on express js using passport-local passport js?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

i am working on a project where it has three companies(i.e compA, CompB, compC).
Each company has their own users. 
Here is my schema for user, where the user can be associated with particular company

```
    const UserSchema = new Schema({
        name:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        company:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        password:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        role:{
            type: String
        }, 
        date:{
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }   
    })

const User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema)
```

My only concern is how to redirect user to a specific page based on the company he is associated with.

Right now i am using this code as my login and after successive login it goes to the 'add' page. Is there any way so that i can redirect specific logged in user to the specific page?

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next)=>{

    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/ideas/add',
        failureRedirect: './login',
        failureFlash: true
    })(req, res, next)
})
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you'd redirect them to the same route, and use dynamic templates to let each user see a specific page according to their company.

Comment: This question is really more deep rooted than the question suggests, what you are asking here is how do you implement [multitenancy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy), it's a question that's been answered a few times on here before but it's also one I'd consider overly broad.

Answer (score 0):

I think 2 ways for your question.

1. not use passport,and write redirect url in site_config.js

```
site_config['url_base_on_company'] = {'a'=>'www.a.com','b':'www.b.com'};
const site_config = require('site_config');
User.findOne({where,'attributes': ['id','company']}.then(user=>{
    if(!user){
    // redirect relogin page
    //return
    }
    //session
    redirect(site_config[user['company']]);
});
```

2. use passport and in your `/ideas/add` page , require site_config and redirect. But it's not good for db. In first idea, you only to access db once, but second idea should twice. Of course, session(save in memery like redis) maybe better than db to get user'company .

Comment: Thank you for suggestion :) i really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

Authentication code is like

```
 passport.authenticate('local',function (err, user, info) { 
     if(err){
      res.redirect('/login')
     } else{
      if (! user) {
        res.redirect('/login')
      } else{
        req.login(user, function(err){
          if(err){
            res.redirect('/login')
          }else{

                 if(user.company == 'company1'){
                   res.redirect('url for company1')
                    }
                if(user.company == 'company2'){
                   res.redirect('url for company2')
                    }

          }
        })
      }
     }
  })(req, res);
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. i achieved this by assigning company name while creating user and when users loges in it checks for the company that is assigned to and redirects them accordingly